# How to run Apache Flume on http source including path url?

Tags: apache, flume

I am running an `Apache Flume` `http` source on `localhost` and binding it to a port, as described in the documentation:

```
agent.sources.httpSource.type = http
...
agent.sources.httpSource.port = 80
```

Now my source is listening on `http://<ip>:80`. How can I modify it so it could run with a path in the url? like so: `http://<ip>:80/example_path`?

I didn't find anything in the documentation and in the web concerning this issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to simply sent the data to `http://<ip>:80/example_path`? As far as a I know, it should work, independently of the path within the URL. A very different thing is if you want to implement a specific behaviour depending on the path. In that case, you will have to create a custom handler for the HTTPSource source by extending [`HTTPSourceHandler`](http://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/source/http/HTTPSourceHandler.html).